# Shutting off Compute engine VMs with Scheduler

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-scheduler, google-cloud-compute-engine

In our GCP project we have a few VMs in Compute engine for some testing purposes. Collogues often forget them running after work. Is it possible to schedule a cron job with Cloud Scheduler, that turns off the machines at a certain hour every day or should I use some other GCP service for that?

I went to the VM settings but couldn't find such options. Is it possible that startup/shutdown options are available only at creation time?

Comment: This [blog](https://medium.com/google-cloud/schedule-vm-restart-using-instance-schedule-in-gcp-19ab36624e3d) written by Vishal contains information on how to schedule restarts  for your compute instances. Hope this might help you

Comment: Whoa, that was way easier than I thought and always before my eyes. Looks like sometimes it's better not to think about overcomplicated approaches.

Comment: Hi `Kristian Kotomanov`, I hope that my suggestion has helped you. For the better visibility of community I am going to post this as an answer, revert back if you are still facing some issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in this blog written by Vishal Bulbule, you can schedule your VM restarts by following the below steps:

> - Go to compute Engine page.
> - Click the Instance schedules tab at the top of the page
> - Click Create schedule. The Create a schedule pane opens.
> - Enter a Name. Optional: Enter a Description.
> - In the Region drop-down menu, select the location for this instance schedule.
> - Define when the instance schedule starts and stops any attached VM instances.
> - If you need VM instances to start or stop at a specific time, schedule the operation 15 minutes earlier than needed. Make sure each start and stop operation are at least 15 minutes apart.
> - Enter a Start time, a Stop time, or both in 24 hr format or use cron expression.
> - Optional: In the Initiate date field, type or click date_range to select the date and time when you want this instance schedule to begin. If omitted, the schedule is effective immediately.
> - Optional: In the End date field, type or click date_range to select the date and time when you want this instance schedule to end. If omitted, the schedule is effective indefinitely.
> - Click Submit. Click on the name of the instance schedule that you want to attach. The Instance schedule details page opens.
> - Click Add instances to schedule.
> - The Add instances to schedule pane opens. Select the checkbox for each VM instance that you want to attach this schedule to Instance.
> - Click Add.

If you want to have additional features you can use some third party tools as mentioned in the blog.

**Note:** The steps given above are taken from the blog which has been embedded in the content above